# Components are getting cached in Angular2 - preventing view caching

Tags: javascript, caching, angular

in Angular 1 includes were automatically cached in the browser. A popular workaround was to add a version as a query string in data includes.

How can caching be prevented or controlled in Angular2?

i.e. updating / releasing a view and reflecting changes when that page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If webpack is used to build the app, there are build-in support to add hash to filename, example:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: { 'app': './src/main.ts' },
    output: {
        path: root + '/dist',
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].bundle.js'
    },
```

So the dist directory will look something like below:

```
dist
├── assets                                                                                                                             
├── index.html                                                                                                                         
├── inline.js                                                                                                                          
├── main.800a8a9b422ccd7272ce.bundle.js                                                                                                
└── styles.f8225afc6bf827fa5376.bundle.js
```

If you [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to generate and build your angular2 project, the above is automatically handle for you.